# siss download folders from one server and move to another

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am looking at download all folders from one server and copying to another with siss

I have looked at ftp task this downloads only folders though.

I need to download folders recursively like to

```
/media_gallery/1/800
/media_gallery/2/800
/media_gallery/3/800
/media_gallery/4/800
/media_gallery/4/500
```

Any help on this would be most appreciated

Comment: Do you mean all the content in the folders? if so, what are you planning on doing with the files? loading to a DB ?

Comment: all the folders with each folder and the files so in this case 1,2,3,4 and the images within each folder. Same structure on one server to the next so in effect everything in media_gallery. They are already in the database

Comment: if this is just a task of moving files, I don't think *SSIS* is the tool to use for this.  I think you'd be better off using a utility, or developing something to move them.

Comment: any ideas what tool?

Comment: If the running process has the permissions it needs on both ends, XCOPY will do this.

Comment: What's wrong with setting up an FTP task with wildcards? i.e. set /media_gallery/* as the source and a directory path as the destination and set it running. It **should** copy everything from /media_gallery down to your destination